# Unexpected behavor zipping an iterator with a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

While trying to solve a particular [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37038/find-the-maximum-operation) question, I came across a particular scenario, which I was having difficulty in understanding the behavior.

The scenario was, `zip`ing an iterator with a sequence, and after the transpose operation, the iterator was one past the expected element.

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> zip(it, range(5))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
>>> next(it) #expecting 5 here
6
```

Am I missing something obvious?

**Note** Please provide credible references for answers that may not be obvious

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that, the `5` is consumed when `zip` tried to zip the next items. Zip stops when one of its arg is "empty":

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> zip(range(5),it)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
>>> it.next()
5
```

By reversing the order, zip knows that it can stop and do not consume the next item from it

Comment: `I suspect that, the 5 is consumed when zip tried to access the next step` .. but why is it so. This is off course obvious, but I need to know why?

Comment: On that sixth iteration, the first thing `zip` will do is call your iterator. Then it will go to `range`, which will fail, and the zipping stops. But you can't un-iterate that item and get `5` again. You're forced to move forward, so that `5` is lost forever to time.

Comment: @Abhijit Zip stops when one of its arg is "empty". But in order to know wether `it` is empty or not, it has to do a `.next()` on it.

Comment: So really you want to know why it does `.next()` instead of checking `.hasNext()` first?

Answer (score 1):

If you want references you can check the [izip documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). It gives an equivalent implementation:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

Since `list(izip(*args))` is expected to have same behavior as `zip(*args)`, the result you got is actually the logical behavior.